# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when running "sorter.s"

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

In our exercise, we're going to write a program that when given a list of (x, y)-coordinates
it sorts them on just the y-dimension and then prints the result.

We have some code snippets that I want to use by linking them:

- parsing.s: pastebin.com/Mum2atVN
- fileHandling.s: pastebin.com/NgxVN5Rg
- allocate.s: pastebin.com/uMQJj16w
- insertionSort.s: pastebin.com/fPRzzHaJ

allocate (allocate.s) This function asks the OS to change the size of
the data segment in the running program, thereby getting more space.
As argument you simply pass the number of bytes needed in %rdi. A
pointer to the allocated memory is returned in %rax.
Note that memory is never freed, so there really is not much management of memory, and you should be careful if you allocate memory in
a recursive function.

getFileSize (fileHandling.s) When you have opened a file you can get
its size (in bytes) with this function. Pass the file descriptor for the
file as argument.

getLineCount (parsing.s) When you have read the contents of a file into
a buffer, this function can count how many coordinates are in it (by
counting the number of newline characters). This will allow you to
allocate the appropriate amount of memory for the parsed coordinates.
• The first argument must be the address of the memory with the
data.
• The second argument must be the length of that piece of memory.

parseData (parsing.s) This function converts the ASCII representation of
the coordinates into pairs of numbers.
• The first argument must be the address of the text buffer to parse.
• The second argument must be the length of that text buffer.
• The third argument must be a pointer to a piece of memory to
write the parsed coordinates to.

I've deciced to go with insertion sort, and then made a "main sorter".
My sorter.s

```
.section .data
input_buffer:
    .space 1000                               # Reserve a larger buffer, adjust as needed
    
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

   # Get the number of command-line arguments and the arguments themselves
    pop %r8             # number of arguments
    pop %r8             # program name
    pop %r8             # first argument after program name (this should be the filename)

    # Use the filename obtained from the command line
    movq %r8, %rdi     # Load address of filename into rdi

    # Open the file
    movq %r8, %rdi
    movq $0, %rsi 
    movq $2, %rax
    syscall
    test %rax, %rax     # Check if open was successful
    js .LError          # Jump to error handling if the result was negative

    movq %rax, %r9      # Store file descriptor in r9
    
    # Step 2: Get the file size
    call getFileSize           # call the function
    movq %rax, %r9             # store file size in r9

    # Step 3: Allocate buffer to read the file
    movq %r9, %rdi             # set size as argument to allocate
    call allocate              # call the function
    movq %rax, %r10            # store buffer address in r10

    # Step 4: Read the file into the buffer
    movq $0, %rax              # syscall number for read
    movq %r8, %rdi             # file descriptor
    movq %r10, %rsi            # buffer address
    movq %r9, %rdx             # file size
    syscall                    # read() call

    # Step 5: Count the number of coordinates in the file
    movq %r10, %rdi            # buffer address
    movq %r9, %rsi             # file size
    call getLineCount          # call the function
    movq %rax, %r11            # store line count in r11

    # Step 6: Allocate space for the coordinates
    movq %r11, %rdi
    shlq $4, %rdi              # 2 * 8 * line count bytes
    call allocate              # call the function
    movq %rax, %r12            # store coordinates address in r12

    # Step 7: Parse the coordinates into the allocated space
    movq %r10, %rdi            # buffer address
    movq %r9, %rsi             # file size
    movq %r12, %rdx            # coordinates address
    call parseData             # call the function

    # Step 8: Sort and print the coordinates
    call printCoordinates

    # Close the file
    movq $3, %rax       # syscall number for close
    movq %r9, %rdi      # file descriptor
    syscall

    # Exit the program
    movq $60, %rax      # syscall number for sys_exit
    xor %rdi, %rdi      # exit status (0)
    syscall

# Function to print a number to stdout
printNumber:
    # Check if the number is 0
    test %rdi, %rdi
    jz .LprintZero

    # Convert the number in rdi to ASCII and print it
    movq $10, %rbx          # divisor
    leaq .Lbuffer(%rip), %r8 # buffer to store ASCII characters
    leaq .LbufferEnd(%rip), %r9 # End of buffer
    addq $15, %r8           # point to the end of the buffer

    # Convert number to ASCII
.LconvertLoop:
    xorq %rdx, %rdx         # clear any previous remainder
    divq %rbx               # divide rdi by 10, quotient in rax, remainder in rdx
    addb $0x30, %dl         # convert remainder to ASCII

    # Check if we're still within buffer bounds
    cmpq %r8, .Lbuffer(%rip)
    jl .LError              # If we've gone out of bounds, jump to error

    decq %r8                # move buffer pointer back
    movb %dl, (%r8)         # store ASCII character in buffer

    test %rax, %rax         # check if quotient is zero
    jnz .LconvertLoop       # if not, continue loop

    # Print the number
    movq $1, %rax           # syscall number for write
    movq $1, %rdi           # file descriptor for stdout
    movq %r8, %rsi          # buffer containing ASCII number
    movq $16, %rdx          # maximum possible length for the number
    subq %r8, %rdx          # actual length
    syscall                 # write() call
    ret
    
.LprintZero:
    movq $1, %rax           # syscall number for write
    movq $1, %rdi           # file descriptor for stdout
    leaq .Lzero(%rip), %rsi # address of the zero character
    movq $1, %rdx           # length of the character
    syscall                 # write() call
    ret
    
.Lbuffer:
    .space 16               # buffer to store ASCII representation of the number
.LbufferEnd:
.Lzero:
    .byte 0x30              # ASCII representation of zero

    # Print newline
    leaq .Lnewline(%rip), %rsi
    movq $1, %rdx            # length of newline character
    syscall                  # write() call
    
    ret

# Print the sorted coordinates
printCoordinates:
    movq %r11, %rcx           # rcx will be our counter for the number of coordinates

    # Step 8: Sort the coordinates
    movq %r12, %rdi            # Starting address of the coordinates
    movq %r11, %rsi            # Number of coordinates
    call insertionSort         # Call the sorting function

    # Step 9: Print the sorted coordinates
    movq %r11, %rcx            # rcx will be our counter for the number of coordinates

.LprintLoop:
    test %rcx, %rcx           # Check if counter is zero
    jz .LprintEnd             # If yes, printing is complete

    # Print x-value
    movq (%r12), %rdi         # Load x-value of the coordinate into rdi
    call printNumber          # Call the function to print it

    # Print tab
    movq $1, %rax             # syscall number for write
    leaq .Ltab(%rip), %rsi    # Load address of the tab character
    movq $1, %rdx             # Size of tab character
    syscall                   # write() call

    # Print y-value
    movq 8(%r12), %rdi        # Load y-value of the coordinate into rdi
    call printNumber          # Call the function to print it

    # Print newline
    movq $1, %rax             # syscall number for write
    leaq .Lnewline(%rip), %rsi # Load address of the newline character
    movq $1, %rdx             # Size of newline character
    syscall                   # write() call

    addq $16, %r12            # Move to the next coordinate
    dec %rcx                  # Decrement counter
    jmp .LprintLoop           # Continue with the loop

.LprintEnd:
    ret

.Ltab:
    .byte 0x09                # Tab character
.Lnewline:
    .byte 0x0A                # Newline character

.LError:
    # Handle the error or simply exit
    movq $60, %rax     # syscall number for exit
    movq $1, %rdi      # status code 1
    syscall            # exit() call
    
    # Exit with an error status
    movq $60, %rax      # syscall number for sys_exit
    movq $1, %rdi       # exit status (1 for error)
    syscall
```

How can I fix this issue?

I've tried to run through gdb:

There's no problem of assemblying them and then linking them together. When I try to run the program, it gives me a segmentation fault:

```
─── Output/messages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004011d6 in insertionSort ()
─── Assembly ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 0x00000000004011d6  ? mov    0x8(%r13),%r15
 0x00000000004011da  ? cmp    %r14,%r12
 0x00000000004011dd  ? jl     0x4011f4 <insertionSort+62>
 0x00000000004011df  ? mov    (%r14),%rdi
 0x00000000004011e2  ? mov    %rdi,0x10(%r14)
 0x00000000004011e6  ? mov    0x8(%r14),%rdi
 0x00000000004011ea  ? mov    %rdi,0x18(%r14)
 0x00000000004011ee  ? sub    $0x10,%r14
 0x00000000004011f2  ? jmp    0x4011da <insertionSort+36>
 0x00000000004011f4  ? mov    0x0(%r13),%rdi
─── Breakpoints ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[1] break at 0x0000000000401000 for *_start hit 1 time
─── Expressions ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── History ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Memory ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Registers ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      rax 0x0000000000403000      rbx 0x0000000000000000      rcx 0x0000000000000305         rdx 0x0000000000403000      rsi 0x0000000000000306      rdi 0x0000000000403000      rbp 0x0000000000000000
      rsp 0x00007fffffffdfc0       r8 0x00007fffffffe326       r9 0x0000000000000000         r10 0x0000000000403000      r11 0x0000000000000306      r12 0x0000000000403000      r13 0x0000000000403010
      r14 0x0000000000403000      r15 0x0000000000000000      rip 0x00000000004011d6      eflags [ PF IF RF ]             cs 0x00000033               ss 0x0000002b               ds 0x00000000        
       es 0x00000000               fs 0x00000000               gs 0x00000000        
─── Source ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─── Stack ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x00000000004011d6 in insertionSort
[1] from 0x0000000000000000
─── Threads ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[1] id 14906 name sorter from 0x00000000004011d6 in insertionSort
─── Variables ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: You did not show the segfault. You just showed the program being stopped at the breakpoint you set. Also that's a lot of code. Reduce it to make a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not that good with assembly, so I thought I did... my bad. Also that's my sorter.s I tried to write... sorry for it being that long. I hope you can use this, ran "stepi" in "gdb":

I've updated it

Comment: That means your `r13` is invalid. Works backwards to see why. Also you don't seem to have posted the code for the sort and the code you did show has bad formatting, please fix that too using the button on the toolbar.

Comment: Hi Jester, thanks for the feedback - hopefully it looks more clean now haha. :D

Comment: Yeah formatting is better, but pieces are missing, it does not assemble.

Comment: I have parsing.s, allocate.s, fileHandling.s and my insertionSort.s. I think that's the reason.
parsing.s: https://pastebin.com/Mum2atVN
fileHandling.s: https://pastebin.com/NgxVN5Rg
allocate.s: https://pastebin.com/uMQJj16w
insertionSort.s: https://pastebin.com/fPRzzHaJ

Comment: You don't even get to loading the data. Already `getFileSize` fails since you don't pass the `fd` in `rdi`. You save the `fd` into `r9` instead of `r8` and promptly overwrite it with the size and eventually pass the file name into `read` which expects the `fd`.  Later you try to use `r11` and `rcx` across `syscall` which clobbers both. Also your debug printing does not print any numbers, only the tabs and newlines. By the time you get to `.LstartSort` both `rdi` and `rsi` are already destroyed by your useless debug print. All of this before you even start sorting.

Comment: Ohh, I see now. This made things clearer, will try that :)